# Find a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the interior of $A$, the closure and the set itself all have a different number of connected components

Tags: general-topology

I thought that $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 1\}$ at first but now I’m second guessing myself and I think it's wrong. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: You don't want $A$ to be open because you want the interior of $A$ not to be $A$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$ is open, its interior is the set itself. Something like $(0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$ could work though.

Comment: @player3236 $A=\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$ is a bit annoying because, depending on where they stand on $\emptyset$ being connected, some autors would say that $A^\circ$, $A$ and $\bar A$ have respectively $1$, $\aleph_0$ and $1$ connected components, while others would say that the numbers are $0$, $\aleph_0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Then we should union some other interval to be safe. Empty sets sure are annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\{ -1 \} \cup [0,1) \cup (1,2] \cup \{5\}$.

The set has 4 components, the closure - 3, the interior - 2.

Comment: so is the closure {-1}U[0,2]U{5} and the interior (0,1)U(1,2) ?

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take $A=\Bbb Q$ and check that it works.

Comment: so does does the set A have infinitely many connected components, the closure of A has 1 and the interior has 0?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.